# How to get a website's body width with selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using python 2.7 and selenium webdriver, I want to test whether a website is mobile friendly or not by doing the following:

1. Opening a website in a "mobile mode"-enabled Chrome browser (using `mobile_emulation`)
2. Getting the `body` width (in pixels) of the website
3. When the `body` width of the website is larger, lets say 900px, than the width of most mobile phones, 400px for example, then I know that the website is not mobile friendly.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": {"width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0},
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"}

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.nl/')

body_width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth;")

print(body_width)
```

Result:

```
912

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Problem: the correct `body` width of the mobile version of the [website](https://www.tripadvisor.nl/) is 360px in this case and not 912px (used Chrome's "device toolbar" in dev tools to check). So my script isnt working properly. I have this issue with other URLs aswell. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass the `chrome_options` to driver, see the followings:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', crome_options=chrome_options)
```

how to do it:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
>>> driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.nl/')
>>> driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth;")
360
```